# How to color shell output in runtime

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed, colors

When I do `svn up` i get ~100 lines output in average. Plus there are X-teen externals that update for ~30s total (they pop-up one after another every 2-3s).

I thought of coloring (maybe transforming) this output so that I can see it more clearly.

I know I can use `sed` to do that but it takes in a nasty-formatted regex - lots of escaping chars.

`perl` on the other hand takes much cleaner regex but it waits for entire input before printing output - I get the 30s of nothing and BAM entire output appears at once.

up.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

svn up $@ \
    | grep -vE "^\s*$|revision" \
    | ${arhbin}/coloring/svn.sh \
```

${arhbin}/coloring/color_definitions.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ${arhbin}/coloring/color_definitions.sh

cat \
    | perl -pe 's/(^ *A.*$)/'$GREEN'\1'$NORMAL'/igs' \
    | perl -pe 's/(^ *D.*$)/'$RED'\1'$NORMAL'/igs' \
    | perl -pe 's/(^ *C.*$)/'$RED_BG'\1'$NORMAL'/igs' \
    | perl -pe 's/(^ *[?].*$)/'$BLUE'\1'$NORMAL'/igs' \
    | perl -pe 's/(^ *G.*$)/'$BLUE'\1'$NORMAL'/igs' \
```

How can I color the output of a command in runtime using Perl/Python like regex?

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: I'd start by making sure nothing is buffered.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, red hat to be precise

Comment: @simbabque how would i do that?

Comment: you should be able (with a minimal amt of extra research) to chain all the substitutions into one call to `perl`. Otherwise that will seem really slow. Something like `perl 's/(^ *A.*$)/'$GREEN'\1'$NORMAL'/igs;/(^ *D.*$)/'$RED'\1'$NORMAL'/igs;....'` . Good luck.

Comment: Note: Don't generate code! Don't use `\1` in replacement expressions. (Use `$1` or `${1}`.) `perl -pe's/(^ *A.*$)/'$GREEN'\1'$NORMAL'/igs'` should be `perl -pe's/(^ *A.*$)/$ENV{GREEN}$1$ENV{NORMAL}/igs'` (if the vars are exported) or `perl -pe'BEGIN { $c=shift; $n=shift; } s/(^ *A.*$)/$c$1$n/igs' "$GREEN" "$NORMAL"` or `C="$GREEN" N="$NORMAL" perl -pe's/(^ *A.*$)/$ENV{C}$1$ENV{N}/igs'`

Comment: Adding `$| = 1;` to your Perl programs will disable their buffering. You might need to use `unbuffer` for the other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can use `stdbuf` to adjust io buffering. Like this:

```
stdbuf -oL svn up "$@" | perl ...
```

Comment: Great, `stdbuf` is exactly what I needed, thank you.
this is actual working solution:
`svn up $@ | stdbuf -oL grep -vE "^\s*$|revision" (...)`

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you!